# minitoc not work

Tags: minitoc, etoc

I try to use minitoc but I don't get the style like I want :

[image]

here the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{mathptmx} 
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} 
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \graphicspath{ {images/} } 
 \usepackage[a4paper,top=30mm,left=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=20mm]{geometry} 
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{lastpage}
 \usepackage{stackengine}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{minitoc}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \input{Configuracion.tex}
 \begin{document}
 \rmfamily
 \input{Portada.tex}
 \newpage 
 \large\hspace{-18pt}Chairman of the jury :\\
 \hspace{30pt}protractor:\\
 framing:\\
 \begin{center}
 \centering \large Academic year 2020 / 2021
 \end{center}
 \makeatletter
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{150pt}{0pt}%Spacing above = 150pt
 \chapter*{dedication}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 %\thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage
 \newpage
 dedication 
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{150pt}{0pt}%Spacing above = 150pt
 \chapter*{thanks}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 \newpage
 %%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}contenido
 \tableofcontents
 \adjustmtc
 \newpage
 %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de figuras} 
 \listoffigures
 \newpage
 %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de tablas}
 \listoftables
 \justify
 \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
 \onehalfspacing % Interlineado de 1,5 
 \afterpage{\null\newpage}   
 \input{Abstract.tex}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
 \input{Introduction}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
 \input{01_Introduccion.tex} 
 \input{chapter1.tex}
 \newpage % En una nueva página
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía} 
 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \bibliography{bibliografia} 
 \end{document} `
```

here the configiration.tex

```
  \definecolor{gris}{RGB}{220,220,220}

  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
  \addto\captionsspanish{
   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of materials }
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Índice de figuras}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
        }
  \fancyhf{}

  \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries{page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries{page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of       \pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \pagestyle{plain}

  \restylefloat{table}
```

here the chapter1.tex

```
 \dominitoc
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{ chapter 1}
 \minitoc
 \section{section one}
 \section{Two}
 \subsection{One}
 \subsection{Two}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to something others can copy and test as is

Comment: I add all the code

Comment: As you can see I can't get the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose some changes to the preamble,  `Configuration.tex` and `chapter1.tex`

(1) Delete a duplicate `\usepackage{hyperref}` and load as the last package.

(2) Delete a duplicate `\usepackage{lipsum}`

(3) Comment `\usepackage{minitoc}`. We are going to use the package `etoc` instead, incorporated in `Configuration.tex`

(4) Use `\localtableofcontents` to print the chapter table of content. See `chapter1.tex`. I added `\singlespacing` before and  `\onehalfspacing` after to save some space.

(5) Comment all `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{..}` after a `\chapter` to avoid duplicates in the table of contents. Use only after `\chapter*` if needed.

(6) Comment all `\adjustmtc`, they are not needed.

(7)  Minor fixes added to the `fancy` and `plain` styles to avoid printing the page number twice.

[image: x]

This is main file

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{images/}} 
\usepackage[a4paper,top=30mm,left=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%%\usepackage{minitoc} % not used
%%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%%\usepackage{lipsum} % duplicate

\input{Configuracion.tex}

\usepackage{hyperref} % last package

\begin{document}
    
%   \dominitoc
    
    \rmfamily
%   \input{Portada.tex}
    \newpage 
    \large\hspace{-18pt}Chairman of the jury :\\
    \hspace{30pt}protractor:\\
    framing:\\
    \begin{center}
        \centering \large Academic year 2020 / 2021
    \end{center}
    \makeatletter
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{150pt}{0pt}%Spacing above = 150pt
    \chapter*{dedication}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \newpage
    dedication 
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{150pt}{0pt}%Spacing above = 150pt
    \chapter*{thanks}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \newpage
    %%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}contenido
    \tableofcontents
%   \adjustmtc
    \newpage
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de figuras} 
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de tablas}
    \listoftables
    \justify
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    \onehalfspacing % Interlineado de 1,5 
    \afterpage{\null\newpage}   
    \chapter{Abstract}
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \chapter{Introduction}
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
%   \input{01_Introduccion.tex} 
    \input{chapter1.tex}
    \newpage % En una nueva página
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía} 
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%   \bibliography{bibliografia} 
\end{document} `
```

This is `Configuration.tex`

```
\usepackage{etoc} % added
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname}}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}}

\definecolor{gris}{RGB}{220,220,220}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %changed
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\addto\captionsspanish{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of materials }
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Índice de figuras}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries{page \thepage\  of \pageref{LastPage}}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % not in fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
%   \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries{page \thepage\ of  \pageref{LastPage}}} % not in plain
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{plain}

\restylefloat{table}
```

This is `chapter1.tex`

```
% \dominitoc
%\tableofcontents

\chapter{Un capítulo}
\singlespacing  % save some space
\localtableofcontents
\onehalfspacing % go back to the normal setting of the document

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsec One}
\subsection{Subsec Two}
```

Comment: thank you friend that means a lot to me